# Running my app shows default activity not found! I do some changes in the manifest file please change the manifest file into correct form

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

It is the android manifest file in my project!
when i run this project it shows default activity not found!
Please guide and help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ShanjosTech.onlineschool">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Registeration"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".app_bar_with_bottom_navi"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please show error message also with code, because question is not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```